# Using "sent" label in a variable for Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, label, gmail-imap

In a Google Apps script user created labels can be used (removed from an email for example) by running 
`var labels = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name);`
However I could not find a way to put the "sent" label in a variable. How is this possible?

I want to remove the sent label from the message automatically after a certain number of days in order to keep the Sent Folder in IMAP small. The archive button in Gmail and the moveThreadsToArchive(threads) method do not work for sent mail for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is impossible, as in gmail "sent" is an information, it's not a label.
You don't have the ability to say I never sent this message.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
GmailApp.search('is:sent');
```

to access/look at the sent mailbox